# How to paste together all the objects in an environment in R?

Tags: r

This seems like a simple question, but I can't find a solution. I want to take all of the objects (character vectors) in my environment and use them as arguments in a paste function. But the catch is I want to do so without specifying them all individually.

```
a <- "foo"
b <- "bar"
c <- "baz"

z <- paste(a, b, c, sep = " ")
z
[1] "foo bar baz"
```

I imagine that there must be something like the `ls()` would offer this, but obviously

```
z <- paste(ls(), collapse = " ")
z
[1] "a b c"
```

not `"foo bar baz"`, which is what I want.

Comment: Are you sure you won't have any other variables at all in your workspace? This seems like an odd request. How did you create all those variables originally. There may be a better way like creating those values in a list in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mget` to return the values of the objects in a `list` and then with `do.call` `paste` them into a single string

```
do.call(paste, c(mget(ls()), sep= " "))
```

As the `sep` is `" "`, we don't need that in `paste` as it by default giving a space

```
do.call(paste, mget(ls()))
```